# How can i deploy the kepler_scientific_workflow_run_engine in docker container?

Tags: docker, deployment, workflow

I would like to deploy the engine of kepler scientific workflow in docker?
But i could not the .war file in the kepler_installer. Should i create it ? 
If yes how can i create ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check if a simple docker run of the [kepler/kepler](https://hub.docker.com/r/kepler/kepler/) image is enough (see its [Dockerfile here](https://github.com/Kepler-Project/releases-docker/blob/master/kepler-2.4/Dockerfile), based of the [kepler-base Dockerfile](https://github.com/Kepler-Project/releases-docker/blob/master/kepler-base/Dockerfile))

That way, there would not be any need to create a war.

If was writtern 2-3 years ago for Kepler 2.4 though. The [current version](https://kepler-project.org/users/downloads) is 2.6.